# Django python contact email form error post not allowed 405

Tags: python, html, django, contact-form, http-status-code-405

I don't know why i get this error in the bash:

> Method Not Allowed
>   (POST): /curriculum/ [14/Sep/2017 20:47:24] "POST /curriculum/
>   HTTP/1.1" 405 0

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView from Profile.forms import ContactForm from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError, EmailMessage from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect from django.shortcuts import render, redirect from django.template import Context from django.template.loader import get_template



# Create your views here. class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'index.html', context=None)

class ProjectsPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'projects.html'

class TutorialsPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'tutorials.html'

class ArticlesPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'articles.html'

class LanguagesPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'languages.html'

class VideosPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'videos.html'

class CurriculumPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'curriculum.html'


def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    form_class = ContactForm

    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact'
            , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'email'
            , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('message', '')

            # Email the profile with the 
            # contact information
            template = get_template('templates/contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "Your website" +'',
                ['juanmacedoal@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('curriculum')

    return render(request, 'PageJMMA/Profile/templates/index.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url from Profile import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^curriculum/$', views.CurriculumPageView.as_view(), name='curriculum')    ]
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

curriculum.html (only the form part):

```
<div class="w3-col m6">
        <form method="POST" action="" role="form">
          <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
            <div class="w3-half">               
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="contact">
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half">
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="message">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.as_p }}              
              <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">SEND</button>
        </form>
      </div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post function should be inside TemplateView to override default post of TemplateView. Generic TemplateView is not meant to be used like this but anyway overriding post method should work.

```
class CurriculumPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'curriculum.html'


    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        form_class = ContactForm

        # new logic!
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = form_class(data=request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                contact_name = request.POST.get(
                    'contact'
                , '')
                contact_email = request.POST.get(
                    'email'
                , '')
                form_content = request.POST.get('message', '')

                # Email the profile with the 
                # contact information
                template = get_template('templates/contact_template.txt')
                context = Context({
                    'contact_name': contact_name,
                    'contact_email': contact_email,
                    'form_content': form_content,
                })
                content = template.render(context)

                email = EmailMessage(
                    "New contact form submission",
                    content,
                    "Your website" +'',
                    ['juanmacedoal@gmail.com'],
                    headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
                )
                email.send()
                return redirect('curriculum')

        return render(request, 'PageJMMA/Profile/templates/index.html', {
            'form': form_class,
        })
```

Also I would recommend rather using [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview)